# Percurso em Árvore Binária C++

Tags: c++, lógica, árvore

Estou resolvendo esse exercício : http://br.spoj.com/problems/PREEMPOS/, mas não sei a lógica de, a partir do resultado da busca em uma árvore de pré-ordem e ordem, chegar ao resultado de pós-ordem, ou seja, ele me dar o resultado da busca em pré-ordem e em ordem e tenho que mostrar a pós-ordem. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Ja existe uma pergunta semenlhante : Da uma olhada no link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002234/how-do-i-output-the-preorder-traversal-of-a-tree-given-the-inorder-and-postorder